# $f(\vec{x_1}+\vec{x_2})=f(\vec{x_1})f(\vec{x_2})$

Tags: functional-equations

What is the general solution to $f(\vec{x_1}+\vec{x_2})=f(\vec{x_1})f(\vec{x_2})$ where $\vec{x}$'s are in discrete vector space $x\in \{n_1\vec{e_1}+n_2\vec{e_2}+n_3\vec{e_3},n_1,n_2,n_3 \in Z\}$?

Comment: Is $f$ required to be linear?

Comment: $f:Z\oplus Z\oplus Z\to {\rm where?}$

Comment: @ Boris, Thanks. To $C$

Comment: @ Andreas, I think No.

Answer (score 1):

For $\vec x_1=\vec x_2=\vec 0$ you have
$$
  f(\vec 0+\vec 0)
=
  f(\vec 0)f(\vec 0)
\quad\text{so}\quad
  f(\vec 0)=f(\vec 0)^2
$$
Therefore, either $f(\vec 0)=0$ or $f(\vec 0)=1$.

1. If $f(\vec 0)=0$, then for every $\vec x$ you have $f(\vec x)=f(\vec x+\vec 0)=f(\vec x)f(\vec 0)=0$. So in this case $f\equiv 0$ (note that such $f$ satisfies the assumptions).
2. If $f(\vec 0)=1$, then for every $\vec x$ you have
   $$
     1=f(\vec x-\vec x)=f(\vec x)f(-\vec x)
   $$
   therefore $\forall x~f(\vec x)\neq 0$. If $\vec x=n_1\vec e_1+n_2\vec e_2+n_3\vec e_3$ then
   $$
     f(\vec x)
   ~=~
     f(\vec e_1)^{n_1}\cdot
     f(\vec e_2)^{n_2}\cdot
     f(\vec e_3)^{n_3}
   $$
   so $f$ is fully determined by the image of a basis. Conversely, chosing 3 real numbers (or complex, or whatever the codomain of $f$ is) not null $f_1,f_2,f_3$ you have that
   $$\tag{F}
     f(n_1\vec e_1+n_2\vec e_2+n_3\vec e_3)
   ~=~
     f_1^{n_1}\cdot
     f_2^{n_2}\cdot
     f_3^{n_3}
   $$
   works.

Comment: Andreas, Perfect

Answer (score 0):

$f\in {\rm Hom}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^3Z,C(\cdot))\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^3{\rm Hom}(Z,C(\cdot))\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^3C(\cdot)$

Here $C(\cdot)$ is the multiplicative group of $C$.